# Way to add multilevel list to Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Is there a way to implement a multilevel list in Excel?

Something like the following:

```
1. XXXX
 1.1. XXXX
  1.1.1. XXXXX
  1.1.2. XXXXX
 1.2. XXXX  
 1.3. XXXX
2. XXXX
```

Comment: Create a raw data table, then create a macro that formats the raw information into a new sheet. The raw data would for example would have 5 rows. 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2, 1.3 and 2. Then you'd write a macro to format the information as you like. if you use a multi indented list as the bottom answer suggest, you lose most benefits of excel to format and manipulate the data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input, there's no strict requirement about auto numbering, so using `Indent` feature is the first thing came into my mind:

[image: List with Indent]

If you want auto numbering as well - this may be done using macro / UDF only (without intermediate / temporary sheets). However, pure formula solution is possible, but won't be flexible and very easy.

Comment: That would defeat the entire point of excel lol because you wouldn't be able to do any macro's or associate the indented cells to their parents.